# One event for many actions

Tags: javascript, events

Is it possible to use one event handler function to change the color of many elements in the same time ? I tried but my code doesn't work.

Only the first variable "a" is actually changing. I don't understand why.
Maybe i dont understand how event handler works...
By the way if you have any idea to reduce the code ;-)

```
const buttonCreateur = document.getElementById('buttonCrea');
const buttonDeveloppement = document.getElementById('buttonDev');
const buttonDifficulte = document.getElementById('buttonDiff');

//GestionEvenement
const createur = () => {
    let tabCreateur = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','j','k','l','n','q','r','t','u','v','w','x'];

    tabCreateur.forEach((variable) => {
        let el = document.getElementById(variable)
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(12, 182, 190)'
    });

}

buttonCreateur.onclick = createur;
```

Comment: What is your error and what does your HTML look like.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the letters in your array are defined as string variables this won't work. Try the code snippet. As long as they're valid strings and valid id's the below should work.

```js
const buttonCreateur = document.getElementById('buttonCrea');

//GestionEvenement
const createur = () => {
  let tabCreateur = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

  tabCreateur.forEach((variable) => {
    let el = document.getElementById(variable)
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(12, 182, 190)'
  });

}

buttonCreateur.onclick = createur;
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
<div id="f"></div>
<div id="g"></div>
<br/>

<button id="buttonCrea">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: That's my bad. I made an edit where I forgot to make the letters strings... Just waiting for my updated edit to go through!

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Maybe your button's id is incorrect. Is it actually `buttonCrea` or is it something like `buttonCreate`

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change all of them. The `forEach` will loop through all of the variables in the array and apply the color.

Codepen with a minimum example:
https://codepen.io/Daniel_I_Am/pen/VwwVQvj

Answer (score 0):

Your post seems to be not complete. 
The way you described it should work without any issues.

```js
const buttonCreateur = document.getElementById('buttonCrea');

let el1 = 'el1';
let el2 = 'el2';
//GestionEvenement
const createur = () => {
    let tabCreateur = [el1, el2, 'el3', 'el4'];

    tabCreateur.forEach((variable) => {
        let el = document.getElementById(variable)
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(12, 182, 190)'
    });

}

buttonCreateur.onclick = createur;
```

```css
.element {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:5px;
 }
```

```html
<button id="buttonCrea">Click me</button>
<div class="element" id="el1"></div>
<div class="element" id="el2"></div>
<div class="element" id="el3"></div>
<div class="element" id="el4"></div>
```